# App Engine Python won't start

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I don't know what changed, but suddenly none of my Python App Engine projects will start on my PC. They start on my MacBook just fine, so there's something about the installation on my PC that's messed up. I've tried going back to 1.8.8, but that doesn't work. I've also tried using a fresh Python installation, but that didn't work. I've even tried using port 8080 (I usually use port 80, as I run the app launcher as admin).

This is what shows up in the error log when I click start on one of my projects:

```
2014-02-05 10:42:24 Running command: "['c:\\users\\jonathan\\appdata\\local\\enthought\\canopy\\user\\scripts\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=80', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\Users\\jonathan\\My Repositories\\my-project']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 197, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 193, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.admin import admin_server
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\admin\admin_server.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.admin import console
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\admin\console.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 69, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import wsgi_server
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 31, in <module>
    from cherrypy import wsgiserver
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\__init__.py", line 278, in <module>
    _pydoc._builtin_resolve = _pydoc.resolve
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'resolve'
2014-02-05 10:42:32 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Also, I'm using Windows 7 x64. My original installation of Python is from Enthought x64, but I did try using the basic x64 Python as well. As mentioned, I downgraded from 1.8.9 to 1.8.8, to no avail.

Comment: should it be pythonw?

Comment: As far as I know it's always used pythonw. I tried specifying python.exe — no dice, same error.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick Google search, other users are [suggesting it's a bug in pyvenv](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pylons-discuss/FpOSMDpdvy4). Since not very many people are still using CherryPy, and it seems to only manifest itself in whatever CherryPy is doing there, that's probably it.

Bug the gist is that somewhere, only on Windows, you have a pydoc.py file which is being imported instead of the standard library's pydoc file.

So, find the offending pydoc.py file in your import path, and rename it. You can most likely find it by doing something like this:

```
import pydoc
print pydoc.__file__
```

Comment: I think you mean a bug in [pyvenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), not [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).  (pyenv hasn’t been ported to Windows and its author says it [never will be](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/62)).